# VS2019 C2675 and C2100 error from xtree in c++ when compiling a single file that defines a method in a class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I got some error messages when I try to compile `cppTableMaker.cpp` but it points to a library not create by me.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cppTableMaker, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>cppTableMaker.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xtree(1373,13): error C2675: unary '++': '_Iter' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Iter=std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>
1>        ]
1>G:\My Drive\coding\C++\cppTableMaker\cppTableMaker.cpp(31): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert<std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>>(_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::wstring,
1>            _Ty=std::vector<std::wstring,std::allocator<std::wstring>>,
1>            _Pr=std::less<std::wstring>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::wstring,std::vector<std::wstring,std::allocator<std::wstring>>>>,
1>            _Iter=std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>
1>        ]
1>G:\My Drive\coding\C++\cppTableMaker\cppTableMaker.cpp(31): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert<std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>>(_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::wstring,
1>            _Ty=std::vector<std::wstring,std::allocator<std::wstring>>,
1>            _Pr=std::less<std::wstring>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::wstring,std::vector<std::wstring,std::allocator<std::wstring>>>>,
1>            _Iter=std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xtree(1374,36): error C2100: illegal indirection
1>G:\My Drive\coding\C++\cppTableMaker\cppTableMaker.cpp(183,1): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
1>INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe'
1>    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>Done building project "cppTableMaker.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Seems like it comes from:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "cppTableMaker.h"
#include "common.cpp"
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <sstream>
//bunch of functions and methods, and the table::modernTable::column class. (there's no main())
std::vector<int> table::modernTable::ins(std::vector<std::wstring> values)
{
    this->row ++;
    auto local_data = this->data;
    std::vector<int> local_colMaxLen = this->colMaxLen;
    int loopCount{ 0 };
    for (auto const& [key, val] : local_data)
    {
        local_data.insert(key, std::wstring(values.at(loopCount)));  //there's some info pointing to the first column of this line.
        local_colMaxLen.at(loopCount) = max(local_colMaxLen.at(loopCount), max(values.at(loopCount).length(), key.length()));
        loopCount ++;
    }
    this->colMaxLen = local_colMaxLen;
    this->data = local_data;
    return local_colMaxLen;
}
```

included header file `cppTableMaker.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#ifndef cppTableMaker_h
#define cppTableMaker_h

namespace table {
    class modernTable {
        public:
        //variables
        std::map<std::wstring, std::vector<std::wstring>> data;
        int row{ 0 };
        std::vector<int> colMaxLen{};
        //init
        modernTable(std::map<std::wstring, std::vector<std::wstring>> data_INPUT, int row_INPUT, std::vector<int> colMaxLen_INPUT);    //constructer
        // ~modernTable();   //destructer
        //methods
        std::vector<int> ins(std::vector<std::wstring>);  //this function might be the cause
        std::wstring get();
        std::vector<std::wstring> rm(int rowNum);

        class column;
        auto col(std::wstring name);

        void mv(int index);
        void mvto(int index);
    };
    //other classes
}
#endif
```

There's nothing special about `common.cpp`. It only contains a `max()` function.

So what is the problem of my script? What does it mean? I changed all `++` to `+1` and the problem still exist. It just doesn't make sense that the error occurs in a standard library.  Can I get rid of it? How and why?

Comment: The type of value of data is `std::vector<std::wstring>`, but you are trying to insert `std::wstring`.

Comment: Thanks!  That fixes the problem! case closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

map::insert want the iterator and value or std::pair.

if you relplace the problem row to pair, you code will be compile

```
    //local_data.insert(key, std::wstring(values.at(loopCount)));  //there's some info pointing to the first column of this line.
    std::pair<std::wstring, std::vector<std::wstring>> value = std::make_pair(key, std::vector<std::wstring>{values.at(loopCount)});
    local_data.insert(value);  //there's some info pointing to the first column of this line.
```

But I think you want somesing like this:

```
    val.push_back(values.at(loopCount));  //there's some info pointing to the first column of this line.
```

For do push into val, you should make non-const reference to for-variable

```
//for (auto const& [key, val] : local_data)
for (auto & [key, val] : local_data)
```

BTW if you will convert type of max argument from size_t to int, you can use std::max:

```
local_colMaxLen.at(loopCount) = std::max(local_colMaxLen.at(loopCount), int(std::max(values.at(loopCount).length(), key.length())));
```

Other way to use `std::max` is change type of `counts` from `int` to `size_t`.